# Generate image file not equivalent to R Studio Output

Tags: r, plot, histogram

I'm using the following R code to generate Histograms of the attributes of a data frame. The heading of the histogram is Histogram of df[[i]] in the file, while R Studio displays the correct "Histogram of x" or "Histogram of y". What am I doing wrong?

```
df <- data.frame(x=runif(20), y=runif(20))
analyzedata <- function(df){
  for(i in names(df)){
    fit <- hist(df[[i]],main=paste("Histogram of" , i))
    png(filename=paste("/home/jabro/histogram_",i,".png"))
    plot(fit)
    dev.off()
  }
}
```

[image: Wrong Title]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hist function does two things. It calculate the histogram data and also plots the data. When you assign the return value, ie `fit<-hist()`, you are only capturing the histogram data and not the plot settings. Any custom properties that you passed along for plotting are not preserved in that object.

If you just wanted to set the variable name, you could do

```
analyzedata <- function(df){
  for(i in names(df)){
    fit <- hist(df[[i]],main=paste("Histogram of" , i))
    fit$xname < - i
    png(filename=paste("/home/jabro/histogram_",i,".png"))
    plot(fit)
    dev.off()
  }
}
```

or if you wanted complete control over the title, you can repeat the `main=` in the plot.

```
analyzedata <- function(df){
  for(i in names(df)){
    fit <- hist(df[[i]],main=paste("Histogram of" , i))
    png(filename=paste("/home/jabro/histogram_",i,".png"))
    plot(fit,main=paste("Histogram of" , i))
    dev.off()
  }
}
```